# Testtools compile error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

I am getting the following error when compiling my application.
-6248 Could not find dependent file Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, or one of its dependencies of component ValidState.Primary_output   ISEXP : warning : -6248: Could not find dependent file Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, or one of its dependencies of component Myapplication.Primary_output.
When i double click the error it opens the Flexera knowledgebase which leads me to believe it might be an installshield issue.

It may be related to installshield as i have added an installation project but this was working fine. i have tried reinstalling visual studio 2012 and installshield and have applied the latest updates. Installshields knowledgebase does not help me at all nor google. I am at a total loss here.

Comment: What .NET Framework are you targeting? And which version of VS 2012 do you have (ie. does it come with the Test Tools)?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2012 premium. .net framework 4.5.  I dont even know what test tools are but i just noticed that in the debug folder there are the dll's Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll / Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.dll / Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll / Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting /  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common & Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension